# How many singleton classes can we use in one android app?

Tags: java, android, class, singleton

I want to know if I can use multiple singleton classes in an android app. Is it possible?
All of the answers I'm getting are about singleton class instance but that is not my question.

Comment: As many as your memory can store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use as many singeltons as you like.
Singleton is just a pattern:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern